# How to make a QuickAssist link through email access

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I wanted to send a link for **Quick Assist** to my grandpa through **email**, so I don't need to tell him to go through the procedure (Start, then type Quick Assist and click the Quick Assist app) instead I would just send him the link through email and he would **open the app (**Quick Assist**) automatically just by clicking that link?**

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.elegantmedia.com.au/blog/everything-need-know-app-links-mobile-app-equivalent-website-urls/) an app need to enable App Links to accept these kinds of deep links. It doesn't look like Quick Assist has that kind of functionality--only a few of the most popular apps would.

Comment: It should have the same procedure as doing the Teams app, someone sends you the meeting link so that generated link triggers your Teams app which by clicking it will open your pre-installed Teams on your computer, same would be with Quick Assis I believe but cant seem to figure out how to make it possible.

Comment: Something like this but with Quick Assist   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Comment: Not every app has this capability. It has to be coded for this to work. It looks like this is not a feature of Quick Assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`ms-quick-assist://`** in your HTML code:

```
<a href="ms-quick-assist://">Click here to open the support session</a>
```

This will open quick assist.

Comment: I made an [edit] to your answer to correct the formatting. Previously, the markup wasn’t being displayed. As part of that, I made the assumption that the `<<` and `>>` were mistakes. If not, and that was intentional here, please accept my apologies, and be sure to [edit] your answer to correct that.

Answer (score -1):

I know that holding Ctrl+Win+Q opens quick assist, so maybe you could use that to speed up the process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).